# How to disable core dump of a specific process (Syslog-ng in my case) of Systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, linux-kernel

I want to permanent disable generating core-dump of a specific process/service of systemd.

Answer (score 3):

According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/syslog-ng), the systemd service running syslog-ng is named `syslog-ng@default.service` in Arch.

Run `systemctl edit syslog-ng@default.service`, and type in the following lines:

```
[Service]
LimitCORE=0
```

Then save and exit. Run `systemctl restart syslog-ng@default.service` to make the setting take effect immediately.

But the fact that syslog-ng is producing a core dump means that *syslog-ng is crashing*. That is not supposed to happen in the first place, and disabling the core dumps won't stop that.

Syslog-ng is a very mature program, and so it should be very stable.

- Your installed syslog-ng might be somehow corrupted on disk; if so, reinstalling it might fix it.
- If your system has failing RAM or other hardware faults, it might cause running programs to become corrupted and crash: since syslog-ng starts very early in the boot process, it might essentially always end up to about the same memory location. If that memory is failing, it might cause the crashes and resulting core dumps... but other programs would be crashing too if they end up using the same faulty memory location(s).
- If your system has been hacked, or it is infected by malware, the intruder might be actively causing your syslog-ng to crash to avoid the intruder's actions getting logged. If you suspect this has happened, a full reinstallation is the only way to be absolutely sure all the changes made by the intruder/malware are gone.

Comment: Thank you! Its working.